# Pytest throws 'attempted relative import beyond top-level package'

Tags: python, pytest

I know this question has been asked before but i cannot seem to find a solution.

This is my folder structure:

```
folder_name/

  __init__.py
  start.py

  src/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    api.py
   

  tests/
     __init__.py
     thetest.py
```

Start.py:

```
from src.app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

App.py:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

Api.py:
Here are all the endpoints

My server works fine.

However, when i introduce pytest into the equation, it fails.

I use this line:
from ..start import app
import pytest

and i get this error.

I have tried placing these lines in the start of `thetest.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

But the error remains.

Comment: Run the tests with a simple `pytest` from the top folder of your project, without `sys.path` modifications and relative imports. Pytest will discover the tests on its own if you have followed the naming conversions.

Comment: This is exactly what i do, and i get this result...

Comment: I have the same issue. I can make `unittest work`, but not `pytest`. Pytest seems to ignore `--rootdir`. I can set it many levels higher, but it changes nothing with `pytest` (unlike unittest).

Comment: Try running your tests with `python -m pytest`, that way your working dir is added to path automatically. Also, if you haven't changed your test discovery settings, testing modules need to start with "test_" for pytest to discover them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:
Inside the `thetest.py` file:

```
from start import app
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try using `unittest` for testing:

```sh
cd "folder_name/../" # ! outside folder_name !
python3 -m unittest discover --top-level-directory=. --start-directory=./tests
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this exists.